# How to find MAX over SUMs MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Consider the following scenario :

```
an Item has a Price

a Order contains Items

a Delivery contains Orders
```

I want to query for each delivery, the order with the highest price, where a price of an order is the summation of prices of the contained items.

A simple sufficient schema would look like this :

**Delivery**

*d_id*

**Order**

*o_id*

**Item**

*i_id*,price

**ItemsInOrder**

*o_id*,*i_id*

**OrdersInDelivery**

*d_id*,*o_id*

I am stuck in the point of having the summation results, needing to get the max order per delivery :

```
SELECT d_id,o_id,SUM(price)
from ItemsInOrder
natural join OrdersInDelivery
natural join Item
group by d_id,o_id
```

How should i go from here to get that each d_id, would appear once and aside the o_id with the maximal price summation?

Comment: Subquery with SUM and then SELECT MAX() on it.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: And what do you want when two deliveries have the same maximum price?

Comment: @GordonLinoff whatever you decide is fine, take one of them, arbitrarily.

Comment: @i486 please provide a full answer

Comment: @Strawberry the problem that im trying to solve differs from what i asked, i translated the problem to this one for simplicity, the data and schemas i really use contains lots of noise so i tranformed it to this. I didnt build any sqlfiddle example for this but  i will if i must..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, but none of them was what i was looking for. I finally found what i was looking for and the approach i choose is as follows :

```
SELECT d_id,o_id,sum_price
FROM (
    SELECT d_id,o_id,SUM(price) as sum_price
    from ItemsInOrder
    natural join OrdersInDelivery
    natural join Item
    group by d_id,o_id
    order by d_id,sum_price desc
) as sums
GROUP BY d_id
```

Comment: This very wrong to use GROUP BY In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. According to MySQL document ion : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @OneManCrew Thanks for the heads up that was a very interesting thought, In other cases you may be right but in this case as far as i understand it should work as sum_price is functional dependent on d_id,o_id and can be uniquely determined by them. so this is not the case described in the link you provided.

Comment: I think you didn't understand it right. There is someone that thinks like you and opened a bug to mysql, you can see  answer: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70203

Comment: I have the same problem and tired this answer and every time i getting different result!

Comment: @user2068793 ask a question about it and show your sql query that does that and i will try to help you see why, dont forget to give me a link to it here

Answer (score 1):

You can use Left Joining with self, tweaking join conditions and filters.
In this approach, you left join the table with itself. Equality, of course, goes in the group-identifier.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
        SELECT oid.d_id AS d_id, o_id, SUM(price) AS sum_price
        FROM `OrdersInDelivery` oid
        INNER JOIN `ItemsInOrder` iio USING (o_id) 
        INNER JOIN `Item` i USING (i_id)
        GROUP BY d_id, o_id
      ) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                  SELECT oid.d_id AS d_id, o_id, SUM(price) AS sum_price
                  FROM `OrdersInDelivery` oid
                  INNER JOIN `ItemsInOrder` iio USING (o_id) 
                  INNER JOIN `Item` i USING (i_id)
                  GROUP BY d_id, o_id
                )b
    ON a.d_id = b.d_id  AND a.sum_price < b.sum_price
WHERE b.d_id IS NULL  AND b.o_id IS NULL;
```

Take a look at this query in SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5c04d/1

In that case it's recommended to use `TEMPORARY TABLE`:

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OrderSummary(
     SELECT oid.d_id AS d_id, o_id, SUM(price) AS sum_price
            FROM `OrdersInDelivery` oid
            INNER JOIN `ItemsInOrder` iio USING (o_id) 
            INNER JOIN `Item` i USING (i_id)
            GROUP BY d_id, o_id
    );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OrderSummary2(
     SELECT * FROM OrderSummary
    );

    SELECT a.*
    FROM OrderSummary a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderSummary2 b
        ON a.d_id = b.d_id  AND a.sum_price < b.sum_price
    WHERE b.d_id IS NULL  AND b.o_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approach adds an unnecessery join and code complexity, and also a temporary table may lead to performance issue because of the lose of a proper index.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `natural join`.  They are an error waiting to happen, because they depend on the *names* of columns in the tables -- not even using properly and explicitly defined foreign key relationships.  Use `on` or `using` instead.

This type of query is painful in MySQL, because MySQL does not support CTEs (common table expressions) nor does it support window functions.  So, the query is more complicated than in other databases:

```
select oid.d_id, o_id, SUM(price)
from OrdersInDelivery oid join
     ItemsInOrder iio
     using (o_id)
     Item i
     using (i_id)
group by d_id, o_id
having sum(price) = (select sum(iio2.price)
                     from ItemsInOrder iio2 join
                          Item i2
                          using (i_id)
                     where iio2.d_id = iio.d_id
                     group by iio2.o_id
                     order by sum(iio2.price) desc
                     limit 1
                    );
```

Comment: How about definning the results of the query in the original question in a temp table and then using it in the max query?

Comment: I prefer not to use temporary tables, unless absolutely necessary.  In this case, it does simplify the query and -- if you add an index -- probably makes it faster too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing the results that I've got so far so anyone could continue to help you  because i need to leave to airport now :) I'll try to check it again tomorrow if no one figure it out.

its a challenging question guys.

I have already prepared some samples here :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4fed2

And the latest query i did is :

```
SELECT d_id,OID.o_id,sumPrice
from OrdersInDelivery OID
join (SELECT IIO.o_id,SUM(I.price) as sumPrice
from ItemsInOrder IIO 
join item I on I.i_id = IIO.i_id
group by IIO.o_id) IIO1 on OID.o_id = IIO1.o_id
```

Good luck :)